# Rails Custom generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, thor

Im building a custom generator for my app where I basically want to wrap around the Rails model generator. More specifically, I just want to change the model template being used (I want to add some methods that each model must implement).

Any pointers to the template to override or any other suggestions would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
Just to add, I dont want this to be the default model template, I want to be able to use it only when I use my generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some more mucking around and i found the answer. The active record model generator is [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord/lib/rails/generators)